# How to resize image to 100% screen width when lower than image's?

Tags: html, css

How to resize an image to 100% screen width (keeping proportion) when the screen width is smaller than image's original width, but prevent enlarging the image greater than its original dimensions when screen is bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max-width` for re-sizing and `height:auto` for same proportion

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `max-width:100%` for image here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eghdkuuc/)